# How to know avl node status in C?

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, avl-tree

This exercise is not really new to me, but it still is quite advance for me. Being a student, I would like to kindly ask for your help regarding this matter.

I need to understand, not just know, how AVL node deletion works. I've been given this C code that I have to complete to demonstrate how AVL insertion and deletion happens. I've done the basics. It's just the balancing and the rotation that got me dizzy.

Here's the main C file:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include "avl.h"
#define N 10
#define BALANCED 0
#define LEFT_LEANING 1
#define RIGHT_LEANING 2

int main(){
AVL *root=NULL;
int choice=0,x;

    while((choice=menu())!=3){
        printf("Value: ");
        scanf("%i",&x);
        switch(choice){
            case 1: insert_value(&root,x);
                    view(root,2);   
                    break;
            case 2:  delete_value(&root,x);
                     view(root,2);  
        }
    }
}
```

here's the avl header file:

```
#define N 10
#define BALANCED 0
#define LEFT_LEANING 1
#define RIGHT_LEANING 2

//structure for an avl_node
typedef struct node_tag{
    int x, height;
    struct node_tag *parent;
    struct node_tag *left;
    struct node_tag *right;
}avl_node;

//print menu and get user choice
int menu(){
    int choice;
    printf("\n   MENU     ");
    printf("\n[1] - Insert");
    printf("\n[2] - Delete");
    printf("\n[3] - Exit");
    printf("\nYour choice: ");
    scanf("%i",&choice);
    return choice;
}

//find maximum of 2 numbers
int max(int a,int b){
    return(a>b?a:b);
}

//finds the minimum value of the BST
avl_node* minimum(avl_node *rootptr){
    if(rootptr!=NULL){
        while(rootptr->left!=NULL) rootptr=rootptr->left;
    }
    return (rootptr);
}

//update height of a given node
void updateheight(avl_node *temp){
    if(temp!=NULL)
        temp->height = max(temp->left==NULL?-1:temp->left->height,temp->right==NULL?-1:temp->right->height)+1;
}

//left rotate the subtree
void left_rotate(avl_node **rootptr){
}

//right rotate the subtree
void right_rotate(avl_node **rootptr){
}

//determine rotation of node/s
void insert_fixup(avl_node **rootptr, avl_node *temp){
}

//insert value and create node
void insert_value(avl_node **rootptr, int x){
    avl_node *temp;
    temp = (avl_node *)malloc(sizeof(avl_node));
    temp->x = x;
    temp->height = 0;
    temp->parent = temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    insert_node(rootptr,temp);
    insert_fixup(rootptr,temp);
}    

void view(avl_node *root, int tabs){
    int i;
    if(root != NULL){
        view(root->right,tabs + 1);
        for(i=0;i<tabs;i++) printf("\t");
            printf("%2i\n",root->x);
        view(root->left,tabs+1);
    }
}//view the AVL

void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int temp;
    temp = *a; *a = *b; *b = temp;
}//swap values

//look for the successor of a node
avl_node* successor(avl_node *rootptr){
    if(rootptr==NULL) return (rootptr);
    else if(rootptr->right!=NULL) return (minimum(rootptr->right));

    while(rootptr->parent!=NULL){
        if(rootptr==rootptr->parent->right) rootptr=rootptr->parent; 
        else break;  
    }
    return (rootptr->parent);
}

//function for searching the location of the node
avl_node* search(avl_node *root,int x){
    if(root==NULL || root->x==x) return root;
    else{
        if(root->x>x) return(search(root->left,x));
        else return(search(root->right,x));
    }
}    

//function for searching the value of the node
int search_node(avl_node *root, int x){
    if(root==NULL) return 0;
    if(root->x==x) return 1;
    else{
        if(root->x>x) return(search_node(root->left,x));
        else return(search_node(root->right,x));
    }
}    

//function for deleting a node
void delete_value(avl_node** root,int x){
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You should not include all the functions in the header unless they're all `inline` (explicitly `inline`). As written, the header can only be used in one source file in a program. To keep track of the balance, you'll need a couple of bits — or a `signed char`, but may as well make it an `int` since alignment will pad the structure anyway — to record the balance of each node. You maintain it inductively. When there's a single node in the tree, the balance is 0. As you add nodes, you track the balance, updating it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

To understand, You should go through the [Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) and also try to understand pseudo code to understand node insertion and deletion in AVL tree. Also you can go through [Presentation PPT](http://www.slideshare.net/chhatrathapa1/tls-15664085) to understand AVL tree.  And to find status of your node from tree you can use search() function.